# All map tasks reached 100%, but still in running state

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

In my MR job, which does bulk loading using HFileOutputFormat, 87 map tasks are spawned and in around 20 mins all the tasks reached 100%.  Yet the individual task status is still in 'Running' in the hadoop admin page and none is moved to the completed state.  The reducer is always in pending state and never starts.  I just waited but it errored out after the 30 mins timeout.

My job has to load around 150+ columns.  I tried running same MR job with less number of columns and it gets easily completed.  Any idea why the map tasks are not moved to completed state even after reaching 100%?

Comment: could you show us the logs?

Comment: Do you have a combiner configured? How many records are output from the map phase, do you have a single reducer?

Comment: no combiner configured.  yes, a single default putsort reducer for HFileOutputFormat is supposed to run.  9 Million records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One probable cause would be that the output data emitted would be huge. Sorting it, writing it back to disk would be a time consuming thing to do. This is typically not the case.
It would be even wise to check the logs and look out for ways to improve your map-reduce code.